# Netbeans package as exe failing

Tags: java, inno-setup, netbeans-8

Hello I built an application a couple of years ago that I compiled from netbeans into a windows exe with package as in the netbeans IDE.  Recently I had to make a few changes and now it throws an error about iscc and candle when I try to run the same package as.

I found a tutorial on the subject (https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html) on the netbeans site and verified that iscc and candle both worked from the command line.  I have also tried a few different versions of netbeans, java, inno, wix, etc. all with zero luck.  If someone can shed some helpful light on this subject I would be appreciative.

The error:

Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "iscc" (in directory "C:\Users\jemmett.CELLTRON\Documents\NetBeansProjects\IOBoardApp"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
C:\Users\jemmett.CELLTRON\Documents\NetBeansProjects\IOBoardApp\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:3415: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\jemmett.CELLTRON\Documents\NetBeansProjects\IOBoardApp\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:3582: Error:
JavaFX native packager requires external Inno Setup 5+ tools installed and included on PATH to create EXE installer. See http://www.jrsoftware.org/
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have Inno Setup installed?
2. Is Inno Setup configured correctly? (against Netbeans)

It looks like you are trying to call Inno Setup compiler (ISCC) but its destination is unknown for the IDE.

Comment: Well that was my first thought which is why I found this and followed it https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html  am I missing something?  Again I can run iscc from command line, so I would assume that netbeans can find it unless there is a step I missed or is not there.

Comment: Another thing also done was I built a machine from scratch, followed that tutorial, and still got the same error.  I wanted to make sure that it wasn't just something with the other machine that wasn't jiving.

Comment: Is your Path set-up correctly? https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html#tool This manual especially says to add Inno Setup path to system Path variable

Comment: Thanks @slappy, but I followed that document to a T.  Come to find out it builds, just not if you run it with the Application/Package As..